# Embedded cognito form on wix which should have redirected to a payment link not working on Wix

Tags: cognito-forms, wix.com

We have made a website Legalspell pro.com on Wix and have embedded cognito forms to take orders for different services. Form should be submitted and redirected towards a payment link we have added on cognito but none of it is working. a user cannot even submit their forms on our website which is made on wix.

Answer (score -1):

I work with support at Cognito Forms.  If you [Submit a Support Request](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support) , we can take a look at your forms and assist you in troubleshooting.